# Formatting errors when using certain code

Tags: c++, lua

I am using some code to centre some given text, then parse the new string back to Lua so it can send the new message to the destination (the game console of a player, or players).
When I use this code, I always get formatting errors of weird characters appearing on the right side of the console. I have been told that this is a string memory error but the person that told me this doesn't know how to fix this.

The string is cleared before we put the new message into it. I have tried with and without the console colour symbols (a $ followed by an integer of 0-9), and the same problem persists.
With normal non-centred console messages, I do not get this problem. See the image for an example.
[image: The problem: Look at the weird 'Xc' symbols]

*Code:*

```
int CScriptBind_GameRules::CentreTextForConsole(IFunctionHandler *pH, const char *msg)
{
    if (msg)
    {
        const int linelength=113;
        char newmsg[linelength+1];
        for(int i=0;i<linelength;i++)
            newmsg[i]=0;
        for(int i=0;i<linelength;i++)
            newmsg[i]=' ';
        int msglen=strlen(msg);
        int startpos=linelength/2-msglen/2;
        for(int i=msglen-1;i>=0;i--)
            newmsg[startpos+i]=msg[i];
        return pH->EndFunction(newmsg); 
    }
    else
    {
        CryLog("[System] Error in CScriptBind_GameRules::CentreTextForConsole: Failed to align");
        return pH->EndFunction();
    }
    return pH->EndFunction();
}
```

To Send:

```
CMCCPlayer(player, "================================================================================================================");
CMCCPlayer(player, "$4####     ###      ###     ######     ####");
CMCCPlayer(player, "$4##        ###    ###     ##    ##      ##");
CMCCPlayer(player, "$4##         ### ###       ##            ##");
CMCCPlayer(player, "$4## ###      #####         ######   ### ##");
CMCCPlayer(player, "$4##         ### ###             ##      ##");
CMCCPlayer(player, "$4##        ###   ###     ##     ##      ## ");
CMCCPlayer(player, "$4####     ###     ###     ######      ####");
CMCCPlayer(player, "================================================================================================================");
CMCCPlayer(player, "$4");
CMCCPlayer(player, "$4Your Name: "..player:GetName());
CMCCPlayer(player, "$4Your Country: "..Omega.GetCountry(player));
CMCCPlayer(player, "$4Your Domain:"..player.actor:GetHostname());
CMCCPlayer(player, "$4Your Profile ID: "..ProfId(player));
if not player.exp then player.exp = 0 end
CMCCPlayer(player, "$4Your EXP: "..player.exp);
CMCCPlayer(player, "$4");
CMCCPlayer(player, "$4o0o");
```

And the function:

```
function CMCCPlayer(player, msg)
    g_gameRules.game:SendConsoleMessage(player.id,  g_gameRules.game:CentreTextForConsole(msg));
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My impression is that you do not end your strings properly, so you exhaust your console width, which displays some "too long" indicating characters.

Try a

```
 newmsg[linelength] = 0;
```

before the line with the msglen initialization, if you want to fill the full 113 characters line, otherwise add the zero at

```
 startpos + msglen
```

Drop the funny loop which zeroes everything in the message area, as this is rewritten with space characters anyway.
Use rather

```
 startpos=(linelength-msglen)/2
```

to minimize truncation errors.

Comment: The info you provided fixed the problem. Thanks :).

Comment: The program crashes when I use this code multiple times a second (calling around 10 times). Is there a solution to this? I've just reverted back to the broken code and it works flawlessly.

Comment: The zero should be at newmsg[linelength + 1], I updated the answer. The more serious issue is the management of the newmsg array. It is allocated in the CentreTextForConsole() method, but once you leave the method it should be deallocated, as it is a local variable. You might switch to something like char[] newmsg = new char[linelength + 1] but then someone has to deallocated it via delete[], check what the function does which is supposed to call CentreTextForConsole(), does it delete the buffer - if not you must provide a global buffer and manage it.

Comment: @mvm: I fixed the issue by not modifying the startpos calculation. It was getting stuck on this point for some reason.

Comment: When I try it out, the modified version can be larger by 1, than the original version. Let me think what this could cause ..

Comment: You need to ensure that (startpos + msglen - 1) < linelength, if not force it to (linelength - 1), then the 0 at linelength should limit the string. Note that i changed the position back to linelength, from linelength+1.

Comment: Clarify: set msgslen = linelength - startpos in that case.., it should result in the maximum index i: startpos + (linelength - startpos) - 1 = linelength - 1